# Perform 2 sample t-test

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

I have a the mean, std dev and n of sample 1 and sample 2 - samples are taken from the sample population, but measured by different labs.

n is different for sample 1 and sample 2. I want to do a weighted (take n into account) two-tailed t-test.

I tried using the [scipy.stat](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_rel.html) module by creating my numbers with `np.random.normal`, since it only takes data and not stat values like mean and std dev (is there any way to use these values directly).  But it didn't work since the data arrays has to be of equal size.

Any help on how to get the p-value would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As far as I understand, Welch’s t-test is for the unpaired case (i.e. not related samples)...

Comment: You have "(related)" in the question title.  As @rroowwllaanndd points out, Welch's t-test is for independent samples.  If you have something else in mind, please explain.

Comment: I have updated the question. Hope it is more clear now

Answer (score 77, accepted):

If you have the original data as arrays `a` and `b`, you can use [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) with the argument `equal_var=False`:

```
t, p = ttest_ind(a, b, equal_var=False)
```

If you have only the summary statistics of the two data sets, you can calculate the t value using [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats.html) (added to scipy in version 0.16) or from the formula (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t_test).

The following script shows the possibilities.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import ttest_ind, ttest_ind_from_stats
from scipy.special import stdtr

np.random.seed(1)

# Create sample data.
a = np.random.randn(40)
b = 4*np.random.randn(50)

# Use scipy.stats.ttest_ind.
t, p = ttest_ind(a, b, equal_var=False)
print("ttest_ind:            t = %g  p = %g" % (t, p))

# Compute the descriptive statistics of a and b.
abar = a.mean()
avar = a.var(ddof=1)
na = a.size
adof = na - 1

bbar = b.mean()
bvar = b.var(ddof=1)
nb = b.size
bdof = nb - 1

# Use scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats.
t2, p2 = ttest_ind_from_stats(abar, np.sqrt(avar), na,
                              bbar, np.sqrt(bvar), nb,
                              equal_var=False)
print("ttest_ind_from_stats: t = %g  p = %g" % (t2, p2))

# Use the formulas directly.
tf = (abar - bbar) / np.sqrt(avar/na + bvar/nb)
dof = (avar/na + bvar/nb)**2 / (avar**2/(na**2*adof) + bvar**2/(nb**2*bdof))
pf = 2*stdtr(dof, -np.abs(tf))

print("formula:              t = %g  p = %g" % (tf, pf))
```

The output:

```
ttest_ind:            t = -1.5827  p = 0.118873
ttest_ind_from_stats: t = -1.5827  p = 0.118873
formula:              t = -1.5827  p = 0.118873
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Especially for the `stdtr` - very useful

Comment: If one only has the statistics, you can use scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats.html#scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats)

Comment: @JensdeBruijn Thanks for the reminder.  `ttest_ind_from_stats` was added to scipy after this answer was originally written.  I've updated the answer to include it.

Comment: is there  a reason for using `b.var(ddof=1)` instead of `np.std(b)` when using the version with only the statistics?

Answer (score 11):

Using a recent version of Scipy 0.12.0, this functionality is built in (and does in fact operates on samples of different sizes). In `scipy.stats` the [`ttest_ind`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind.html) function performs Welch’s t-test when the flag `equal_var` is set to `False`.

For example:

```
>>> import scipy.stats as stats
>>> sample1 = np.random.randn(10, 1)
>>> sample2 = 1 + np.random.randn(15, 1)
>>> t_stat, p_val = stats.ttest_ind(sample1, sample2, equal_var=False)
>>> t_stat
array([-3.94339083])
>>> p_val
array([ 0.00070813])
```