# calculate p value given mean and std of two pandas series

Tags: python-3.x, scipy

How can I calculate the p-value between two group. I have mean1 and std1 of one group of numbers and mean2 and std2 of second group of numbers.

I dont want to calculate by the two arrays of numbers because they are not accessible.

Thanks

Comment: A "p-value" by itself is meaningless.  Which statistical test are you trying to perform? For example, are you trying to do a two-sample [t-test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test) for equal means?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am trying to do a two-sample t-test for equal means. Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to include that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ttest_ind_from_stats.html), but you will also need the number of values in each group.

For example, suppose group 1 contains 13 values and has a mean of 24.0 and a standard deviation of 2.3, and group 2 contains 16 values with a mean of 26.5 and a standard deviation of 2.9:

```
In [12]: from scipy.stats import ttest_ind_from_stats

In [13]: n1 = 13

In [14]: mean1 = 24.0

In [15]: std1 = 2.3

In [16]: n2 = 16

In [17]: mean2 = 26.5

In [18]: std2 = 2.9

In [19]: tstat, pvalue = ttest_ind_from_stats(mean1, std1, n1, mean2, std2, n2)

In [20]: pvalue
Out[20]: 0.017694241930792689
```

Also take a look at [Perform 2 sample t-test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22611446/perform-2-sample-t-test).